# Where can I find Lucene's wildcard implementation?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

tl;dr - Where does Lucene have the wildcard query implementation?

I am currently writing an elasticsearch native script filter. The need is driven by performing wildcard queries on the entire field (instead of on tokens).

For this, I wanted to write my script to essentially replicate wildcard searching as performed in Lucene. However, I am not sure where to look for the Lucene implementation of wildcard queries ie where exactly IndexSearcher.search() visits the wildcard query node.

Would appreciate any help!

Note: I saw that there is an automaton based solution, but that only works if the automaton is deterministic, but it seems to be not deterministic for *pqr* kind of queries, therefore not functioning for my query.

Answer (score 0):

The Lucene source code is available on Apache's Github [`lucene-solr` repository](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr).

You can find Lucene's `WildcardQuery` implementation [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/5e5fd662575105de88d8514b426bccdcb4c76948/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/WildcardQuery.java).

Comment: Thanks! Seen this before. Where is the automaton used to compare against the field values? I saw that Operations.run(Automaton automaton, String fieldValue) is the method that can run a query against an automaton, but that only works for a deterministic automaton. Not sure how to do this for a non deterministic one.